# Export/Import SudoCommands | freeipa

Tags: freeipa

I have completed testing of a freeipa instance in a lab. I'd like to export all of the SudoCommands that I have defined in the lab to the servers I intend to press into production.

I did an LDAP search to see if I could find an OU that had all of the commands & descriptions I configured in lab (5 pages worth), but found nothing. I performed an pa-server-backup and sifted through that filesystem. The only reference I found to sudo was a couple of berkley databases for host groups and external commands, none of which had any entries.

Is anyone aware of where in the freeipa application the individual sudocommands are stored & how to access them? The CommandGroups & HostGroups I made are easy enough to regenerate from hand.

Answer (score 0):

I found there was another CN on top of cn=sudo,$SUFFIX:

```
cn=sudocmds,cn=sudo,$SUFFIX
```